# Jquery validate text lentgh : javascript say ok maxlength <= 300 but php count 306

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, maxlength

I don't understand why javascript an php aren't agree...

Here is a sample text :

```
Bonjour,
Je suis ravi de soumettre mon problème à la communauté stackoverflow - franchement c'est la meilleure du web pour les questions de codage .
Ce texte est fictif mais illustre bien ce que mes visiteurs parfois postent sur mon formulaire de contact en termes de longueur et contenu.
Merci salut
```

So, if I use in rules (jquery validate) that code:

```
demande: {
required: true,
rangelength: [5, 300],
regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 \'\’\.\,\;\!\?\:@_°àâéèëêîïôùûçÀÂÇÈÉÊËÏÎÔÙÛ\s\S\(\)\/\-]*$/
}
```

or this one:

```
demande: {
required: true,
regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 \'\’\.\,\;\!\?\:@_°àâéèëêîïôùûçÀÂÇÈÉÊËÏÎÔÙÛ\s\S\(\)\/\-]{5,300}$/
}
```

...in both cases jquery reports nothing (implied: text is no more than 300 characters), but then if I test $_POST['demande'] with PHP:

```
echo 'count text = '.strlen($_POST['demande']);
```

...PHP say 306 characters! :o

And If I use this code:

```
if(preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9 \'\’\.\,\;\!\?\:@_°àâéèëêîïôùûçÀÂÇÈÉÊËÏÎÔÙÛ\s\S\(\)\/\-]{5,300}$#", $_POST['demande'])){
echo 'good';
} else { echo 'wrong'; }
```

...PHP say 'wrong'!

So why do you think PHP is not agree?

Comment: The discrepancy is most likely caused by either the line breaks or the diacritics in the string, although I'm not familiar with the specifics of JS/PHP text encoding so I can't give you a definitive answer. I'd suggest starting your research with tyhat

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the strlen error, I have found that mb_strlen is better because of multi byte. So there remains the problem of the regex that PHP does not interpret as Javascript does. Do you know what's wrong with the PHP code (preg_match)?

Comment: This is because strlen in PHP get the length of string in bytes, for your case you should use [grapheme_strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.grapheme-strlen.php) it will give `300`, since it count actual string characters length not bytes length, I suspect that javascript treat all Latin character as PHP `grapheme` characters,  `mb_strlen` will return `303` for your string because its also use bytes length to count characters.

Comment: Awesome! I had never heard of grapheme_strlen. Thank you. Is there something else like that so that PHP can find 300 characters instead of more than 300 characters in my preg_match?

Comment: I think I found the trick for PHP regex: adding the letter u after the final #, so like that it seems to be ok: ...{5,300}$#u

Comment: As an aside, within a *character set*, that is `[]`, you do not need to escape characters with a backslash such as `.`, `(`, `)`, etc. (and certainly not characters such as `;` that never have any special meaning). You will, however, need to escape the `]` character so that it is not interpreted as the end of character class specification. Also, if you do escape things like `\d`, they will have their normal meaning (that is, "digits"). It appears you are matching `\s` *and* `\S`, so that would be everything and anything.